# Does Non-Renewing subscription requires a restore button?

Tags: ios, ios7, in-app-purchase, xcode5

My app got rejected because of restore button on non-renewing in app purchase. Do i have to remove restore button ? If i have to do so then how user will restore his purchases.Please help.

Comment: you can only restore non-consumable in-app-purchases. did you try to restore a consumable in-app-purchase? did you ever restore anything with your restore-button during testing?

Comment: they are not consumables and they must be restorable but if apple doesn't like it ok -- I deleted my answer and all comments and docs just RTFM (but in the end: do what the review team wants)

Comment: @Daij-Djan I updated my answer to make it more comprehensive...

Comment: Can you please provide the specific rejection letter from Apple. I'd like to see the details.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Non-renewing subscriptions are consumable. Therefore they cannot be restored. A restore button therefore makes no sense. You also need some kind of authentication/login system for the user. (See below for detailed explanations.)

Sources:

- [consumable vs. non-consumable in app purchases](http://www.raywenderlich.com/23266/in-app-purchases-in-ios-6-tutorial-consumables-and-receipt-validation)
- [non-renewing subscriptions](http://www.raywenderlich.com/36270/in-app-purchases-non-renewing-subscription-tutorial)
- Update from WWDC2017: In [Session #303](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2017/303/) App Store Engineer Pete Hare explains at 3:00 that a non-renewing-subscription can be seen as "a consumable product with an expiry date on it"

---

There has been some debates in the comments wether non-renewing subscriptions are consumable or not, so I want to say something about it. "Consumable" means that you can consume them multiple times. Like "30 minutes of talking" in a voice-over-IP telephony application. On the other hand, there are non-consumables that you can buy only once. Like when you unlock all levels in a game app. You buy it once, and when you reset the device and redownload the app, you should be able to restore the purchase, so that you don't have to pay twice to unlock all levels. Furthermore, if you don't tap the restore-button in this case but just buy the "unlock all levels" package again, it works, but you will not be charged by apple a second time. That's why it is called non-consumable. It's some kind of metapher. An apple is "consumable". Once it is consumed, it is gone. A chair is non-consumable. You have it as long as you don't destroy it or give it away.

So, it makes sense to regard a non-renewing subscription as non-consumable. If you buy it a second time, you shouldn't pay twice, you should just use the old subscription you already have. If you reset the device, you should be able to restore the subscription once you re-download the app. The restoration is just not done by Apple but by the app itself.

I still regard non-renewing subscriptions as consumable though. I use a simple definition of consumable vs. non-consumable: **An in-app-purchase is consumable, when, from the point of view of the StoreKit API, it can be purchased multiple times in the same week by the same user.** All consumable IAP-items cannot be restored through the StoreKit. All non-consumable IAP-items can be restored through the StoreKit.

So, the developer is himself responsible for restoring the in-app-purchase of a non-renewing subscription, right? No, sorry. How would the app restore the in-app-purchase of a non-renewing subscription? Suppose I have an iPod and I subscribe to 1 month of listening to the [Foo](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Metasyntactic_variable)-radio. Now I want to also listen to the Foo-Radio on my iPad. Soo, I install the Foo-App on my iPad and tap the "restore" button. Well... what is the "restore" button supposed to do? How can it know if I already have purchased a "Foo"-subscription or not, and how long it will still be valid? Answer: it can not. This approach does not work.

In order for a non-renewing subscription to work, you have to login the user first, to tie the subscription to some online account. Username/Password, Open-ID, Login via Gmail, Facebook, etc. all would work. Then, when the user purchases an n-r subscription you have to store the fact that he subscribed on some server and link it to his account on the server. You also have to prevent the user from buying the n-r subscription when he is not already logged in. Let's continue with my iPod/iPad-example above. I download the app on my iPad, I login with Facebook, and voila, I can use the "Foo"-subscription now. There is no need for a "restore" button, because the app should check at login-time which subscriptions the user has.

There will be some additional problems to deal with. (1) For example, nothing prevents the user from logging in into 200 devices. Here the problem is not a user with 200 devices, but a university with 1000 students where 180 students share the same account. (2) If the server crashes, some people will probably lose their subscriptions. Problem (1) can potentially lead to decreased income. Problem (2) can lead to angry and unhappy customers.

Comment: is it possible to Non-Renewing Subscription cancellation ? 
What happen when customers call to Apple and cancel the Non Renewing subscription? how to know which transaction has got cancelled and refunded to customers by Apple. We want to stop subscription for those customers

Comment: @Monish From time to time I have a non-renewable subscription refunds (just like usual refunds).

Comment: This answer is wrong. Apple defines which product types are consumables, and their definition is different. As Chris Prince mentions in his answer, you are **required** to allow users restore this kind of purchases.

Comment: @Theo: I wrote the answer a long time ago. It may not be 100.0% correct in a theoretical sense. However, I am a practice-guy, and I try to give correct, practical and useful guidence. My answer explains how the developer should deal with non-recurring subscriptions. The advice is valid. Users don't care if the purchase is called "consumable" or "non-consumable". But they do care that they are not charged twice when they should be charged only once. The process that I describe is the only way to achieve this. For me, a non-r.-s. is still "consumable", and my reason is explained in the article.

Comment: Yeah, my answer is really right, not just practically right. In [this WWDC2017 talk](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2017/303/) Apple Engineer Pete Hare calls non-renewing-subscriptions "a consumable product with an expiry date on it" (at position 3:00 if you don't want to view the whole video)

Comment: @VladimirShutyuk How do you handle refunds for non-renewable subscriptions? Do you block the user from accessing the resource they subscribed to?

Comment: @FranSevillano No, number of refunds doesn't justify time implementing such a check in my case.

Answer (score 7):

From Apple: "Non-renewable subscriptions. Subscriptions that don’t involve delivering episodic content. Examples include access to a database of historic photos or a collection of flight maps. It’s your app’s responsibility to make the subscription available on all of the user’s devices and to ***let users restore the purchase.*** This product type is often used when your users already have an account on your server that you can use to identify them when restoring content. Expiration and the duration of the subscription are also left to your app (or your server) to implement and enforce." [Italics and bold added] https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/StoreKitGuide/Chapters/Products.html

Comment: Pretending the non-renewing subscription provides access to a database of historic photos and my app allows a user to download such photos to view offline, what should I do with those downloaded photos when the subscription expires? Am I allowed to delete them from the device?

Comment: You might want to prompt the user to renew their subscription, first -- and get more money! :). After that I think it's really up to you.

Comment: @Tim how did you solve your problem? I have the same goal: provide offline access to the app using non renewable subscriptions.

Comment: @Stafox I implemented renewable subscriptions instead. However, I'm pretty sure, that if any subscription expires, you are in rights to restrict access to a paid data in a way you prefer unless a user pays again.

Comment: @Tim ok. that's the case: user might be in offline mode, transaction already has been expired. But Apple successfully charged user and renews the subscription to the next period. You are not able to check it because of no internet connection. What are you do in that case?

Comment: @Stafox, I would probably keep user’s access to paid data until I will become sure, the subscription really did expire

Comment: @Tim thanks. I also thought to do that. Nice to hear that I’m not alone.

Answer (score 2):

Apple Reviewer's current-similar response about Non-Renewing Subscriptions "Your app offers Non-Renewing Subscriptions and this purchasability type must have its own restoring function - if you have removed it please re-implement it. Furthermore, your app must also offer a function, such as account creation, such that purchases can be tracked across all of a user's devices. Please implement a login feature as well as a restore mechanism prior to resubmitting your revised binary for review."

Comment: I have been looking for a more recent update on this issue (as most posts I found were before 2016). Thanks for sharing