# iOS in-app restore purchases nightmare

Tags: ios, in-app-purchase, restore, storekit

I've read ALL the threads etc. on the internet and still am getting back zero restored transactions when I try to restore purchased products (sandbox environment).

I have created 3 Non-renewing products and 2 sandbox testers through iTunes connect.

I have had zero issues setting up the ability to actually purchase products; all is well.

I have created a "restore purchases" button and am trying to get it to work. I've been testing the following: install app and make purchase. Purchase again and it asks if I want to renew. Delete app and log out of app store. Reinstall app and press restore purchases ... zero!!!

Here's some code I'm using:

```
-(void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    //in-app purchase setup
    [[SKPaymentQueue defaultQueue] addTransactionObserver:self];
}
-(void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    //make request for in-app products
    if([SKPaymentQueue canMakePayments])
    {
        SKProductsRequest *request = [[SKProductsRequest alloc] initWithProductIdentifiers:[NSSet setWithObjects:@"product1_id",@"product2_id",@"product3_id",nil]];
        request.delegate = self;

        [request start];
    }
    else
    {
        //alert user
        UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"..." message:@"Please enable In App Purchase in settings" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil];
        [alert show];
    }
}

-(IBAction)restoreTransactionsPressed
{
    _refreshRequest = [[SKReceiptRefreshRequest alloc] init];
    _refreshRequest.delegate = self;
    [_refreshRequest start];
}
-(void)requestDidFinish:(SKRequest *)request
{
    if([request isKindOfClass:[SKReceiptRefreshRequest class]])
    {
        NSLog(@"Got a new receipt... %@",request.description);
        [[SKPaymentQueue defaultQueue] restoreCompletedTransactions];
    }
}
-(void)request:(SKRequest *)request didFailWithError:(NSError *)error
{
    NSLog(@"%@",error.description);
}

-(void)paymentQueue:(SKPaymentQueue *)queue updatedTransactions:(NSArray *)transactions
{
    NSLog(@"updatedTransactions");

    for(SKPaymentTransaction *transaction in transactions)
    {
        NSLog(@"updatedTransaction:%@ ... state:%@",transaction.originalTransaction.payment.productIdentifier,transaction.transactionState);

        switch(transaction.transactionState)
        {
            case SKPaymentTransactionStatePurchased:
                NSLog(@"SKPaymentTransactionStatePurchased");
                //unlock feature code
                [[SKPaymentQueue defaultQueue] finishTransaction:transaction];
                break;

            case SKPaymentTransactionStateFailed:
                NSLog(@"SKPaymentTransactionStateFailed");
                [[SKPaymentQueue defaultQueue] finishTransaction:transaction];
                break;

            case SKPaymentTransactionStateRestored:
                NSLog(@"SKPaymentTransactionStateRestored");
                [[SKPaymentQueue defaultQueue] finishTransaction:transaction];
                break;

            default:
                break;
        }
    }
}

-(void)paymentQueueRestoreCompletedTransactionsFinished:(SKPaymentQueue *)queue
{
    NSLog(@"paymentQueueRestoreCompletedTransactionsFinished");

    NSLog(@"received restored transactions: %i", (int)queue.transactions.count);

    for(SKPaymentTransaction *transaction in queue.transactions)
    {
        NSLog(@"transaction:%@",transaction);
    }
}
-(void)paymentQueue:(SKPaymentQueue *)queue restoreCompletedTransactionsFailedWithError:(NSError *)error
{
    NSLog(@"restoreCompletedTransactionsFailedWithError %@",error);
}
```

Why do I always get back zero restored transactions?

it seems that "restoreCompletedTransactions" isn't in turn calling - paymentQueue:updatedTransactions: if that helps.

I'm unsure that SKReceiptRefreshRequest is necessary, but I've tried both refreshing the receipt before restoring and not refreshing the receipt before restoring.

Please don't post links to thread. I've investigated this for a few Days now! Some people claim that Apple's Sandbox had issues in the past ... could this be the reason? tyvm in advanced; all help is appreciated!

Comment: Can you even restore purchases made in a sandbox environment?

Comment: Unsure, but how would I be able to test my app's restore logic if not?

Comment: You say you have non-renewing products. [Apple's documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/technotes/tn2259/_index.html) says that one of the causes of being unable to restore is: "You were trying to restore non-renewing subscription or consumable products, which are not restorable."

Comment: The only options when I created the products were "consumable, non-consumable, free subscription and non-renewing subscription" ... I want a monthly subscription to some sort of service within my app. This service should not need to be purchased twice if the user has 2 devices. Thoughts?

Comment: I don't know... isn't there such case mentioned in Apple's documentation/programming guides?

Comment: You should look around a bit before asking. I found [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23931586/does-non-renewing-subscription-requires-a-restore-button) after like 30 seconds of searching. This might answer your question.

Comment: No need for sass, I didn't realize that That was the issue. I've been stuck on this for days not realizing that a monthly subscription to something can not be restored. I thank you very much for pointing me in the right direction. Clearly my question Was outlined well enough for you to understand my issue; I was following tutorial after tutorial and reading S.O. post after S.O. post of people having the "same" issue as me, well the issue of it returning to them zero products available for restoration!

Comment: please "answer" the question and I'll gladly accept it as the solution as well as up vote it! TYVM!!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to [Apple's documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/technotes/tn2259/_index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40009578-CH1-FREQUENTLY_ASKED_QUESTIONS), you can't restore non-renewing subscriptions. Also, have a read [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23931586/does-non-renewing-subscription-requires-a-restore-button) for a more detailed explanation.