# Non-renewing sbuscription in iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, in-app-purchase

I want to implement InApp purchase in my iOS video streaming app to do that I need to implement Non-renewing subscription e.g 1 month,3 months, 6 months and 1 year.

I am using Objetive-C in my application.

Can you please tell me how to implement it because as per Apple, developer need to manage subscription expiration date and time.

How to validate receipt ??
How to manage user's subscription on multiple device or restore user's subscription if user login on other device ??

Please help me and let me know if anything is required in Non-renewing subscription.

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

You should go through the in-app purchase programming guide before starting the implementation.
https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/StoreKitGuide/Introduction.html

**Store-kit won't send you any notification in case of subscription end for a non-renewable subscription. You need to calculate the duration on your own and revoke the user's access to your server after that duration.**

To verify the receipt you can do the validation on user's device or on your server, but your server is preferably better and even recommended by apple also.

For restoring the purchase you can go through the following doc
https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/StoreKitGuide/Chapters/Restoring.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008267-CH8-SW9

Comment: can you tell me how user cancel non-renewing subscription and how the app will know that subscription is canceled ??

Comment: If user cancels the subscription you will get the statusUpdateNotification on your server. Please go through the doc for more details about Status Update Notifications https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/StoreKitGuide/Chapters/Subscriptions.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008267-CH7-SW13

Comment: ok but it will happen in the case of auto-renewal subscription right ?? but in non-renewing subscription how will know that subscription is canceled ??

Comment: is there any way to test this case (cancel non-renewing subscription) in Sandbox environment ??

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/165947/discussion-between-abhishek-gupta-and-abhishek).

Comment: as you said :
CANCEL notification is not dependent on auto-renewal or non-renewing. Whenever user cancels a transaction from itunes, you will get notification.

so where i will get on app or on server that the user canceled the subscription ??

Comment: on app or on server ??

Comment: ok so in case of auto-renewal we need to mention server to server notification URL on iTunes so same for non-renewing no need to set any URL or something ??

Comment: A server URL to receive update notifications (JSON object posts) for key subscription events. This is applicable only for apps containing auto-renewable subscriptions. It is recommended to use these notifications in conjunction with Receipt Validation to validate users' current subscription status and provide them with service.

This is mention on iTunes.

Comment: i didn't get my answer for cancellation non-renewing subscription in the comments and how upvote comment answers ??

Answer (score 0):

**Non Renewing subscription**

First of non renewing subscription is the consumable keys that means once it purchased it just purchased. Keep in mind `Storekit` doesnot restore consumable products so you have to manage yourself because `StoreKit` does not do it as it do in Auto-renewable subscriptions and Non-consumable .

More details about Non renewing subscription :
[Does Non-Renewing subscription requires a restore button?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23931586/does-non-renewing-subscription-requires-a-restore-button)

**How to manage?**

To manage your in-app purchase you have to use server DB. You have to store your all purchases in server DB by using post API.

Benefits:

1. You can easily maintain the end date of purchase.
2. You can get each paid account every time user logged in with any device.

**Note:** Maintain your DB according to your need.

Comment: can you tell me how user cancel non-renewing subscription and how the app will know that subscription is canceled ??