# Does non-renewing subscriptions (iOS) need a restore button?

Tags: ios, in-app-purchase

I'm having trouble to get my App approved by Apple because I'm using non-renewing subscriptions.

Now they're saying it needs a Restore button. (Review Guideline 3.1.1)

My App uses a login system to my own server to manage all subscriptions and purchases. So all purchases are automatically restored in the app when the user signs in.

After all, the restore button is really necessary with non-renewing subscriptions? I didn't find anything in the Apple documentation.

I only found that my app is responsible for restoring purchases, but they not specify how.

Answers about this in Stackoverflow are very old, like this one:

[Does Non-Renewing subscription requires a restore button?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23931586/does-non-renewing-subscription-requires-a-restore-button)

Which the user's app got rejected because it had a Restore button.

Comment: A non-renewing subscription is like a consumable in app purchase. The transaction is not re-presented to your transaction observer if you call `restorePurchases`, so I can't see what benefit there would be to having a restore purchase button, however I am not app review, so my opinion is worthless

Comment: You probably need to go back to them. 3.1.1. Says "you should make sure you have a restore mechanism for any restorable in-app purchases." but a non renewing subscription is not restorable